# Multiple screen support on Android

Tags: android, screen

From last few days I'm trying to create an application that can adjust screen according to emulator's size change.. I found the solution that uses multiple screen.

but i am not able to do this
i've taken help from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)  but not able to understand how can i  `setContentView(R.layout.main);` ? because when i am pressing .(dot) after `R` it doesn't show me this below folders..:(
i've created 3 folders named `layout-large`, `layout-small` and `layout-large-land` under the `res` folder in my android application

i've added this into my manifest file..

```
<supports-screens
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:normalScreens="true"
          android:smallScreens="true"       
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

[image]

what thing i am missing over here? i am using android 1.6 thanks in advance
question is whether i've to provide this `main.xml` file to default `layout folder` also? yes then no affect on chage in screen size no then it close my application forcefully i've tried using `API level 7` also but problem remain same
this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_height="360dip">
    <!--
        <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewHelp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    -->
    <!--        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />-->
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewHelp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="8px" android:text="Download this mp3 file"
        android:textColor="@color/white" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="28dip" android:visibility="invisible" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/My_btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="this is button !"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main) would be the same. According to the emulator size android will assume which folder to consider.

Comment: It will not show you any folder name but default layout and its not your headache, Android will automatically choose appropriate folder

Comment: I am totally agree with @Rosalie, android will handle it for you, just give the same named xml file in those folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some layout xmls in these folders before you type dot after R :)
The folders themselves do not generate resource ids, but the xml files in them do.

Comment: but this file must be in m layout folder also? else application close forcefully and if i am provide then it it take it and display no changes on change in screen view my updated code

Comment: You put different layout files in different folders and the Android runtime chooses the one in the folder whose name matches the current device screen display metrics and orientation.
E.g: `setContentView(R.layout.main);` will loads the main.xml in folder `layout-large-port` if the device has a *large* screen and is in *portrait* orientation currently, or in folder layout-small-land if it has a *small* screen and is in *landscape* orientation currently. Android throws an exception in both cases if it can't find a file named main.xml in the desired folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you meant, but this worked for me:
[ScalingLinearLayout](http://www.quadra-tec.net/~floppie/blag/2013/01/scalinglinearlayout-auto-scaling-layouts-in-android/)